# How to forcefully abort thread created by BackgroundWorker without using DoWorkEventArgs Cancel property?

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have one third party dll without source-code which accept file pages array and return book object. That dll have one function GenerateBook(Page[] pages), which execute under BackgroungWorker.

If user press abort button, process should stop generating book. Using cancelAsync(), I can send cancel request to BackgroundWorker thread process. But GenerateBook(Page[] pages) is third party function, so I can't use e.cancel inside that.

Now In this scenario, How to abort background worker process immediately? Please give me suggestion. Right now I am using below code. but that is not working.

```
    public class AbortableBackgroundWorker : BackgroundWorker
    {
        public delegate void ErrorEventHandler(string message, ReportRunStatus status);
        public event ErrorEventHandler foundError;
        public Thread workerThread { get; set; }
        private bool isFromAbort;

        protected override void OnDoWork(DoWorkEventArgs e)
        {
            workerThread = Thread.CurrentThread;
            try
            {
                base.OnDoWork(e);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (!isFromAbort)
                {
                    if (foundError != null)
                        foundError(ex.Message.ToString(), ReportRunStatus.Error);
                }
                e.Cancel = true;
                this.Dispose();
            }
        }

        public void Abort()
        {
            if (workerThread != null)
            {
                isFromAbort = true;
                workerThread.Abort();
                workerThread = null;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do not use such outdated class. Use TPL and `Cancellation Token` for such tasks. Also, aborting the thread is **always** a bad idea.

Answer (score -1):

You may try using asynchronous call using BeginInvoke and EndInvoke. One of the given methods in the reference link should solve the issue.

https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/315582/how-to-call-a-visual-c-method-asynchronously